# SessionId cookie in CakePHP causing the page to hang

Tags: php, cakephp, sessionid

I have been having problems with my CakePHP application. Sometimes (not everytime) my application hangs (continues to load forever) in Chrome (Although I don't think it happens in other browsers). I can fix this by removing the sessionId cookie but I need a permanent solution. I have tried this solution by pixelastic:

http://www.pixelastic.com/blog/273:losing-session-request-cakephp-chrome

but that didn't seem to fix the problem. Does anyone have any ideas? If you need me to provide information, I can and will do that promptly. I am not sure what information to provide.

Comment: Can you at least make the error reproducible? ATM it could just be faulty logic somewhere in your app causing PHP to hang, and we'd have no idea without scanning most of your app's code.

Comment: Yeah it is reproducible but it's not happening every time. I have looked through the code, couldn't find anything. I guess I will do it again. So you think it isnt related to the sessionid cookie?

Comment: As long as you just know that "it's hanging", it could be the cookie, but it could also be a thousand different other things. I'd recommend debugging it with XDebug and seeing where it loops.