# (CakePHP on WAMP) page hangs on load only in IE

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I'm developing an application in CakePHP and I've been debugging it with Firefox. Everything has been great until I decided to test it with IE and came across some very strange behavior. Sometimes pages will not load in IE, they'll just sit there with a loading status. The page that hangs is very simple, only makes use of CakePHP's Html helper to create a single form and does a check with AuthComponent::User() (to see if the user is logged in). I'm convinced the issue has to do with sessions. Say I were to open the page in IE and it does in fact hang, I can't view the page in Firefox until I stop the connection in IE.

Again, this issue does not occur whatsoever in Firefox. I've tried the fixes posted within [SessionId cookie in CakePHP causing the page to hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950385/sessionid-cookie-in-cakephp-causing-the-page-to-hang) but with no luck.

UPDATE: I just installed XDebug. I placed a call to xdebug_break() at the very beginning of index.php in my webroot directoy. When the requests in IE hang, this breakpoint is never triggered. I'm now suspecting WAMP is acting up?

Here is the code the is causing concern, this is in my root controller that all other controllers extend.

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    if($this->Auth->user())
    {
        if($this->Auth->user('roles') == 'admin')
            $this->layout = 'admin';
        else if($this->Auth->user('roles') == 'partner')
            $this->layout = 'partner';
        else if($this->Auth->user('roles') == 'user')
            $this->layout = 'user';
    }

    $this->set('currentController', $this->request['controller']);
    $this->set('username', $this->Auth->user('username'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's an issue with Apache.

Resolved by adding

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

to my httpd.conf

http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=7920